# Group by context and get the sum for lesser than 24h and greater than 24h

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to get the result as

```
{
  context: 'ABC',
  lesser_12h: 32,
  lesser_24: 64
},

{
  context: 'DEF',
  lesser_12h: 12,
  lesser_24: 93
}
```

And for that, I've written this query. But I'm having difficulty in summing the results. It just gives me **0** or **1**, in the **lesser_** variables.

How to get the sum/count?

```js
const aggregation = [
  { $match: { EVENTTIME: { $gte: startDate } } },
  { 
    $group: {
      _id: {
        tech: '$CONTEXT',
        lesser_12h: {
          $sum: {
            $cond: [
              { 
                $lte: [{ $subtract: [ '$EVENTTIME', startDate ] }, 43200000]
              },
              1,
              0
            ]
          }
        },
        lesser_24h: { 
          $sum: {
            $cond: [
              { 
                $lte: [{ $subtract: [ '$EVENTTIME', startDate ] }, 86400000]
              },
              1,
              0
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
];
```

Comment: Can you provide sample input documents? Thanks.

Comment: And `lesser_12h` and `lesser_24h` is become part of the group key. Review your $group stage. It should be: `{ $group: {  _id: { tech: "$CONTEXT" }, lesser_12h: { ... }, lesser_24h: { ... }  } }`

Comment: Hello, I also want to group by those intervals.. So shouldn't they be also included in the _id ?

Comment: Oh that was totally the problem.. Now its working. Can you post it as an answer and also the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comment, the `lesser_12h` and `lesser_24h` fields became part of the group key. The `$group` stage should be:

```
const aggregation = [
    { $match: { EVENTTIME: { $gte: startDate } } },
    { 
      $group: {
        _id: {
          tech: '$CONTEXT',
        },
        lesser_12h: {
          $sum: {
            $cond: [
              { 
                $lte: [{ $subtract: [ '$EVENTTIME', startDate ] }, 43200000]
              },
              1,
              0
            ]
          }
        },
        lesser_24h: { 
          $sum: {
            $cond: [
              { 
                $lte: [{ $subtract: [ '$EVENTTIME', startDate ] }, 86400000]
              },
              1,
              0
            ]
          }
        }
    }
];
```

And the `$group` key:

```
_id: {
    tech: '$CONTEXT',
}
```

can be replaced with

```
_id: '$CONTEXT'
```

as you just group with single field. And in further stages, you access with `$_id` rather than `$_id.tech`.